# javascript to determine if page on remote domain has changed

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I am trying to find a client-side way to determine if a page on a remote domain has changed.

I can't load the page in an iframe and examine its contents due to same origin policy.

So I tried using `.getResponseHeader("Content-Length")` and `.getResponseHeader("Last-Modified")` but apparently these are also restricted by SOP even though FireBug shows `Content-Length` in the console.

Is there a way to do this? I just need a way to know if the page has changed.

Thx

Comment: Can't you use a Server side language ?

Comment: @Boris I am already using server-side as part of this project, but the design spec limits the number of server calls off-site. This is why I want to do this client-side, so that I can make the server-side call only when it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it completely client-side unless the other end supports [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), or some other cross-origin mechanism for doing it. In the absense of that, your only options are:

- Using server-side help
- Using a [signed script](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/components/signed-scripts.html) (which your users would have to grant permission to)
- Using a signed Java applet (which your users would have to grant permission to)
- Using an ActiveX control (which your users would have to grant permission to)

...you get the idea.